# How to replace first word in string using batch?

Tags: string, file, variables, batch-file, replace

Hello StackExchange community!

I am trying to solve the problem of replacing the first word in a row with the other. Type of conversion depends on the first letter of the word.

To the point.
I have a log file (INPUT.txt) in the following form:

```
s272400 616264890454 23.19 14.79
s272400 616264890453 25.11 16.23
s272400 616264890452 24.12 15.73
u272400 616264890451 21.18 16.78
s272400 616264890450 24.19 12.12
u292402a 616264890449 21.18 18.98
s292402a 616264890448 20.13 15.73
```

I would like to look like this:

```
w1 616264890454 23.19 14.79
w1 616264890453 25.11 16.23
w1 616264890452 24.12 15.73
w2 616264890451 21.18 16.78
w1 616264890450 24.19 12.12
w2 616264890449 21.18 18.98
w1 616264890448 20.13 15.73
```

If the string starts with the letter "s" I would change the begining of substring to "w1" if you begin with the letter "u" I would change substring to "w2" as in the example above. The first substring may be of different lengths.

I wrote the code here:

```
@echo off
setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
set "Ver_1=s"
set "Ver_2=u"
set "Ver_1_res=w1"
set "Ver_2_res=w2"
for /f "delims=" %%a in (INPUT.txt) do (
    set var=%%a
    setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
    set value_1=%Ver_1%
    set value_2=%Ver_2%
    set value_res_1=%Ver_1_res%
    set value_res_2=%Ver_2_res% 
    set ProgramVersion=!var:~0,1!

if !ProgramVersion!==!value_1! (
set "var=!value_res_1!"
echo !var!
)
if !ProgramVersion!==!value_2! (
set  "var=!value_res_2!"
echo !var!
)
endlocal
) >> OUTPUT.txt
pause
```

The result (OUTPUT.txt) of this script is as follows:

```
w1
w1
w1
w2
w1
w2
w1
```

Conversion work but lose other information from the log. I am sure that the problem is trivial, but for a long time already, I can not solve it. Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
(FOR /f "tokens=1,*" %%a IN (input.txt) DO (
  set a=%%a
  if "!a:~0,1!"=="s" set b=w1
  if "!a:~0,1!"=="u" set b=w2
  echo !b! %%b
))>output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

when you set the var like "set "var=!value_res_1!" or "set  "var=!value_res_2!", you lose the remaining info. you need to add the remaining data to var when you do the set.

Answer (score 0):

In this method it is simpler to add or modify replacement values; it also run slightly faster...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Define the replacement values
set "res[s]=w1"
set "res[u]=w2"

(for /F "tokens=1*" %%a in (input.txt) do (
   set "var=%%a"
   for /F %%c in ("!var:~0,1!") do echo !res[%%c]! %%b
)) > output.txt
```

You may review the management of arrays in Batch files at [this site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10166386/arrays-linked-lists-and-other-data-structures-in-cmd-exe-batch-script/10167990#10167990).